# Understanding how to use image sprites

Tags: css

I've heard of this method, but I've never tried it before.

Does this only work on hover/mouseover?

Would this work on, on mouse click?

https://jsfiddle.net/mntrmfsb/349/

So, I would be putting this image into an image sprite, but how does that work?

[image: Screenshot]

```
 .playButtonb.active {
   border: 3px solid #e77d19;
   background-image: linear-gradient( to right, transparent, transparent 83px, #e77d19 83px, #e77d19 86px, transparent 86px, transparent 174px, #e77d19 174px, #e77d19 177px, transparent 177px, transparent 260px), url("https://i.imgur.com/yNVkI3W.png");
 }
```

**Or would I be using something like these?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: check this tutorial - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Comment: I had seen that already, but still don't understand how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to indicate correctly position of the item you want to show.

Look this example

[image]

Comment: Would that work in this type of code? https://jsfiddle.net/mntrmfsb/349/

Comment: it will work but I think you should not use sprites with SVG

Comment: I wouldn't be, only with the image. How exactly would I implement it?

Comment: https://24ways.org/2014/an-overview-of-svg-sprite-creation-techniques/
I think it can help you

Comment: Compose your SVG data into one file and then using it like above example

Comment: I'm not doing svg, only the png.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mntrmfsb/351/
You can see how to use sprites with your png images

Comment: How would I add this to active?
background-image: linear-gradient( to right, transparent, transparent 83px, #e77d19 83px, #e77d19 86px, transparent 86px, transparent 174px, #e77d19 174px, #e77d19 177px, transparent 177px, transparent 260px),

https://jsfiddle.net/mntrmfsb/356/